# React-native: How to copy file from ios project folder?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-fs

I have files in assets folder which is created in Xcode under my_project/assets.
I can normally access file in my template WebView with:

source={uri:'ICF-Package/ICFPackage/index.html'}

but I can't copy this file to LibraryDirectoryPath with react-native-fs:

RNFS.copyFile('.ICF-Package/ICFPackage/index.html', RNFS.LibraryaDirectory + '/index.html').then((result) => console.log('DONE')).catch((error) => console.log(error, 'ERROR'));

Please help me with this.

Comment: I wonder why your dest path is RNFS.LibraryaDirectory + '/index.html, it should be a diretory

Comment: We tried giving destination path as RNFS.LibraryDirectoryPath. We got an error saying 
Error: The file “ICF-Package” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

Comment: I read the doc give you a solution, you can try it